# Best learning algorithms concentric and not linearly separable data

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

Below are two scatter plots. The first one is for data points that have values of x and y, and I would like to know if there is a clustering algorithm that will automatically recognize that there are two clusters. They are concentric and not linearly separable. K-means is not right for several reasons. The other plot is similar but it has x, y and color values, and I would like to know what learning algorithm would be best at classifying or predicting the correct color from the values of x and y.[image]

Comment: You can use spherical coordinates and apply ANN or any other linear technique.

Comment: Additional to Ahmed's good comment, a nice [overview of scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/_images/sphx_glr_plot_cluster_comparison_001.png).

Comment: Consider normal clustering of Circle Hough Transforms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform

Comment: k-Nearest Neighbors would be worth trying for the classification problem

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far... but I thought I would stress the point here that I need an algorithm that will automatically recognize that there are two clusters that are not linearly separable. The example I plotted shows two concentric rings, but that may not always be the case. Using polar coordinates with linear regression or Circle Hough Transform to detect circles are not general enough for this problem. :)

Comment: BTW... The k-means clustering algorithm is not good because the mean of all the red dots is the same as the mean of all the blue dots. The k-nearest neighbors algorithm is not good because every blue dot is closer to all red dots than half of the other blue dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got good classifier results for this problem using the sklearn MLPClassifier algorithm. Here is the scatter and contour plots:

[image]

Detailed code at: [https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/couple-scikit-learn-classifiers-peter-thorsteinson](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/couple-scikit-learn-classifiers-peter-thorsteinson/). The simplified code below shows how it works:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix  

# Generate the artificial data set and display the resulting scatter plot 

x = []
y = []
z = []
for i in range(500):
    rand = np.random.uniform(0.0, 2*math.pi)
    randx = np.random.normal(0.0, 30.0)
    randy = np.random.normal(0.0, 30.0)
    if np.random.random() > 0.5:
        z.append(0)
        x.append(100*math.cos(rand) + randx)
        y.append(100*math.sin(rand) + randy)
    else:
        z.append(1)
        x.append(300*math.cos(rand) + randx)
        y.append(300*math.sin(rand) + randy)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.axis([-500, 500, -500, 500])
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z)
plt.show()

# Run the MLPClassifier algorithm on the training data

XY = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
print(XY.head())
Z = pd.DataFrame({'z': z})
print(Z.head())
XY_train, XY_test, Z_train, Z_test = train_test_split(XY, Z, test_size = 0.20)
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(10, 10, 10), max_iter=1000)
mlp.fit(XY_train, Z_train.values.ravel())

# Make predictions on the test data and display resulting scatter plot

predictions = mlp.predict(XY_test)

print(confusion_matrix(Z_test,predictions))  
print(classification_report(Z_test,predictions))

plt.axis('equal')
plt.axis([-500, 500, -500, 500])
plt.scatter(XY_test.x, XY_test.y, c=predictions)
plt.show()
```